# YouTube video Title and View are not printed

Tags: selenium, beautifulsoup, youtube, webdriver

I am trying to print the title and view count of each video on each YouTube channel (which I put in `urls`).
However, it only showed the result of one of the channels (https://www.youtube.com/c/TuckerBudzyn/videos) but didn't show the result of the other channel (https://www.youtube.com/c/LUCKIESTBTS/videos).
I couldn't tell the difference between these two channels, which is the reason why I couldn't solve this problem. If someone can tell, help me, please.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# provide the url of the channel whose data you want to fetch
urls = ['https://www.youtube.com/c/TuckerBudzyn/videos','https://www.youtube.com/c/LUCKIESTBTS/videos']

def main():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\chromedrive\chromedriver.exe')
    for url in urls:
        driver.get('{}/videos?view=0&sort=p&flow=grid'.format(url))
        content = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8').strip()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
        titles = soup.findAll('a', id='video-title')
        views = soup.findAll('span', class_='style-scope ytd-grid-video-renderer')
        video_urls = soup.findAll('a', id='video-title')
        print('Channel: {}'.format(url))
        i = 0 # views and time
        j = 0 # urls
        for title in titles[:10]:
            print('\n{}\t{}\t{}\thttps://www.youtube.com{}'.format(title.text,views[i].text, views[i+1].text, video_urls[j].get('href')))
            i += 2
            j += 1
main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend using the Python package [pytube](https://pypi.org/project/pytube/), which is designed to extract YouTube information.

```
from pytube import YouTube
from pytube import Channel

videos = ['https://www.youtube.com/c/TuckerBudzyn/videos','https://www.youtube.com/c/LUCKIESTBTS/videos']
for video in videos:
    channel_info = Channel(video)
    for url in channel_info.url_generator():
        video_details = YouTube(url)
        print(f'Video Author: {video_details.author}')
        print(f'Video URL: {url}')
        print(f'Video Title: {video_details.title}')
        print(f'Video Number of Views: {video_details.views}')
        # output 
        Video Author: Tucker Budzyn
        Video URL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j8yQO6gsfVI
        Video Title: This Is What My Dog Does When I Hug My Husband
        Video Number of Views: 1106181


        Video Author: Tucker Budzyn
        Video URL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ovyQ1V13BQ
        Video Title: My Dog Stole My Camera!
        Video Number of Views: 805448


       Video Author: Tucker Budzyn
       Video URL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UmVpw2TisOA
       Video Title: My Dog Rents a Log Cabin
       Video Number of Views: 4864017

       truncated....
```

Comment: @CanaryTheBird You're welcome.  I will be posting a 3rd way to extract the content using BeautifulSoup later today.  I also noted that you're a new user of SO, I would recommend looking at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

This answer using *selenium* like your question, but doesn't use *BeautifulSoup*.  With *selenium* you can access the title information and number of views with *xpath*.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument(
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.106 Safari/537.36")
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)

driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/c/TuckerBudzyn/videos')

titles = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="video-title"]')
video_views = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="metadata-line"]/span[1]')

# https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_zip.asp
for title, view in zip(titles, video_views):
    # https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/
    print(f'Video Title: {title.text}')
    print(f'Video Number of Views: {view.text}')
    # output
    Video Title: This Is What My Dog Does When I Hug My Husband
    Video Number of Views: 1.1M views
    Video Title: My Dog Stole My Camera!
    Video Number of Views: 805K views
    Video Title: My Dog Rents a Log Cabin
    Video Number of Views: 4.8M views
    Video Title: My Dog Tries the Obstacle Course Challenge
    Video Number of Views: 1.7M views
    Video Title: Hugging My Dog's Brother for Too Long | Jealous Dog Reaction
    Video Number of Views: 2.7M views

    truncated....
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer using Python *requests* and *BeautifulSoup* to extract the video information that you're seeking.

```
import json
import requests
import re as regex
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


# this function iteration through nested json for specific key

def item_generator(json_input, lookup_key):
    if isinstance(json_input, dict):
        for k, v in json_input.items():
            if k == lookup_key:
                yield v
            else:
                yield from item_generator(v, lookup_key)
    elif isinstance(json_input, list):
        for item in json_input:
            yield from item_generator(item, lookup_key)


response = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/c/TuckerBudzyn/videos')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

# the video information is located in a script tag
for script_tags in soup.find_all('script'):
  
   # the script contains the string "var ytInitialData"
   script_match = bool(regex.findall('var ytInitialData', str(script_tags)))
   
   if script_match:
        # regex is used to extract the content that we want to harvest
        extract_content = regex.match(r'.*(var ytInitialData =)(.*)(;<\/script>)', str(script_tags))

         # load the extract content into JSON 
         content = json.loads(extract_content.group(2))

         # use the generator to extract the dictionary with the 
         # video details
         for video_dict in item_generator(content, 'gridVideoRenderer'):
            for key, value in video_dict.items():
             
                # here are the keys
                # -----------------
                # videoId
                # thumbnail
                # title
                # publishedTimeText
                # viewCountText
                # navigationEndpoint
                # ownerBadges
                # trackingParams
                # shortViewCountText
                # menu
                # thumbnailOverlays
                # -----------------

                if key == 'title':
                    video_title = value['runs'][0]['text']
                elif key == 'viewCountText':
                    video_views = value['simpleText']
```

This is the output:

```
Video Title: This Is What My Dog Does When I Hug My Husband
Video Number of Views: 1,125,048 views
Video Title: My Dog Stole My Camera!
Video Number of Views: 808,420 views
Video Title: My Dog Rents a Log Cabin
Video Number of Views: 4,879,426 views
Video Title: My Dog Tries the Obstacle Course Challenge
Video Number of Views: 1,793,264 views
Video Title: Hugging My Dog's Brother for Too Long | Jealous Dog Reaction
Video Number of Views: 2,775,208 views
Video Title: My Dog Rents a Swimming Pool
Video Number of Views: 12,459,980 views
Video Title: Feeding My Dog Invisible Treats
Video Number of Views: 1,378,288 views
Video Title: Leaving My Dog Alone with a Juicy Steak
Video Number of Views: 4,155,106 views

 truncated....
```